# neovim syntax highlight with large files issue

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, large-documents

I use neovim 0.4.3. When I open a large xml file (about 130-140k lines) syntax highlighting switches off with a message:

> 'redrawtime' exceeded, syntax highlighting disabled

If add this line to my config init.vim:

```
set redrawtime=10000
```

The syntax highlighting works but when I try to scroll up page by page it becomes really slow.

What can be a possible solution or I just need to accept the fact that there is no syntax highlighting for large files in neovim/vim?

Comment: Do you have `g:xml_syntax_folding` set? From the [comments in the code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/xml.vim#L20-L21), "This might slow down syntax highlighting significantly, especially for large files."

Comment: I believe @ChristianBrabandt is the maintainer of XML syntax in Vim, so maybe he might know whether this performance issue with large files is expected?

Comment: @filbranden No, I don't have g:xml_syntax_folding set.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for large files is consistently atrociously slow (especially when the language is hugely recursive à la lisp or xml: C fares much better because it has generally has more consecutive structures than recursive ones). I find it best to turn it off when viewing large documents.

I don’t have anything technical to back this up (links, discussion, timings, etc.), and I would greatly welcome an answer that did.

See also `:syntime`

One tweak can be bumping up the `maxmempattern` to let vim use more memory.

Comment: Looking at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/xml.vim`, I'm not so sure it's that expensive, it doesn't look like it's trying to match tags but only highlight tags, attributes, namespaces, etc. shouldn't be that expensive. There's a comment there about `g:xml_syntax_folding` making things slower, but that's about it...

Comment: @filbranden i’ve has this issue in clojure before where it seemed that having a lot of forms, even if most of them are shallowly nested (which is rare, granted), causes problems. As i said, I dont have anything to back this up, and I’d love to be wrong => maybe there’s an easy fix

Comment: I opened the same large xml file in vs code without any problems and the syntax highlighting worked fine. I think there is some specific issue with neovim/vim and it really frustrates me.

Comment: @Nurjan completely different; Idk what vscode does, but vim’s syntax highlighter is based on regex and a few other things. It’s slow and unwieldy in the long run (though text properties present a new avenue to explore things like tree sitters).

Answer (score 2):

Syntax highlighting is done synchronously in vim, which is why it is slow when dealing with large files.

There's a few highlights you can deactivate to speed things up:

```
set nocursorline
set nocursorcolumn
```

You can also set the minimum / maximum highlighted lines (`:h :syn-sync-maxlines`):

```
syntax sync minlines=200
syntax sync maxlines=500
```

There's a good article about this on [vim fandom](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting).

---

A better way to get fast and consistent highlights is to use the `language server protocol`.

It's not only for highlights though, its first use is indeed completion.

A few vim plugins can use the LSP, here's some of them:

- [CoC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/) (I use this one)
- [Ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale)
- [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp)
- [LanguageClient-neovim](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim)

Setting this up can be a bit tedious, but it's very powerful once it's done.

I'm not sure about the others, but CoC offers highlights out of the box.

Comment: And with text properties, LSPs can start using true ASTs to build highlighting

Comment: I use CoC for autocompletion and it's really nice. You're saying that syntax highlighting is done synchronously in vim, but I thought that neovim is more asynchronous in this sense?

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't say. But through CoC, it should definitely be.